# Config Map in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I am creating a configMap from CSV file using helm tempate but it is getting create different from OC command.

**Heml Template:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: service-config
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.appname }}
data:
{{- $path := printf "%s/application-config/*" .Values.env }}
{{ (.Files.Glob $path).AsConfig  | indent 2 }}
```

**Generated Configmap**

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service-config
  namespace: ''
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
data:
  esm-instrument-type-map.csv: |-
    M-MKT,COB
    CMO,COB
    MUNI,COB
    WARRNT,EQU
    PFD,EQU
```

**OC Command :**

```
oc create configmap test-config  --from-file= ./esm-instrument-type-map.csv
```

**Generated ConfigMap**

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test-config
  namespace: ''
data:
  esm-instrument-type-map.csv: "CORP,COB\r\nEQUITY,EQU\r\nGOVT,TRY\r\nMBS,FNM\r\nST-PRD,COB\r\nM-MKT,COB\r\nCMO,COB\r\nMUNI,COB\r\nWARRNT,EQU\r\nPFD,EQU"
```

As we see, data from the CSV file is in double quotes, when generated by the OC command. I want the same in helm. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Used a dummy csv file but it works the same for me either way. I used the exact syntax as yours for the helm template but the data in config-map does show up in double quotes:

`nile.csv: "Year,\" \"\"Flood\"\"\"\r\n1,9.9974\r\n2,10.5556\r\n3,9.9014\r\n4,11.48\r\n5,12.846\r\n6,11.133\r\n7,10.1126\r\n8,10.306\r\n9,10.498\r\n10,10.306"`

Comment: Not sure how to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: There are multiple ways to write strings in YAML, especially when they have embedded newlines.  Is the file content actually different, or are you just concerned about the inline double-quoted string vs. block-string difference?